# How to write to the Active Directory group property "info" with Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

In the Active Directory Users and Computers GUI, I was able to write a comment in the Notes box. When using Powershell, I can retrieve that with `Get-ADGroup $_ -properties info`. But, while the Set-ADGroup cmdlet has a parameter for description, it does not have a parameter for info. How can I use Powershell to write that property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe using `Set-ADGroup -Instance <ADGroup>` can solve your issue. Retrieve the group, set the desired property on it and try saving it.

Solely based on documentation, don't have and environment to test this.

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-adgroup?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't get how that worked at first. But it looks like that will do it. Get the group and save to a variable like $object, make a change to the Powershell object ($object.info = "whatever"), then use the set cmdlet with -instance $object.